# How do I restore HoldAll, HoldFirst, HoldRest attributes of Inactivated functions

Tags: attributes, hold

Let `f` be defined as follows:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];

f[1+1]
(* f[1+1] *)
```

The `1+1` stays as is.  But if I `Inactivate` `f`:

```
Inactive[f][1+1]
(* f[2] *)
```

it has the paradoxical effect of reactivating the held `1+1`, making it evaluate to `2`.  How do I prevent `Inactive` from killing the attributes of `f`?

note: I am looking for a solution that solves the problem of losing attributes, not one of deactivating `1+1` by doing `f[1+1] // Inactivate`

Comment: Setting `SetAttributes[Inactive[f], HoldFirst]]` fails because `SetAttributes` takes `Symbol` as its first argument.

Comment: Since `f` is deactivated, why should its `Attributes` be still active? Makes sense to me although the question how to workaroud that is interesting.

Comment: One good question after another! +1 again. Perhaps rolling your own version of `Inactive`, e.g. ``myInactive[head_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{head},DownValues[head]={}, (*code*)]`` would work?

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could give some background on what you're trying to achieve, since its not quite clear, why `// Inactivate` doesn't suit you. You might also find `Defer` useful. As I suggested in my previous comment, your desired behavior would appear to suppress only matching of `DownValues` patterns. This can probably be done differently.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need this kind of behavior. Maybe temporary removal of `f`'s `DownValues` would be more appropriate? It'll keep `f`'s attributes, prevent it's evaluation and leave structure of expression unchanged.

Comment: `Inactivate` inactivates *expressions*. The inactivated expression is commonly something you'd use as the head of a composite expression representing a function invocation, but it doesn't have to be. It can be a complex expression that plays the Star Spangled Banner through your speakers when evaluated. `Inactivate` doesn't inspect it or evaluate it.

Comment: I think this is quite impossible.  It is not possible to have `b` held in `f[a][b]`, even though this would be useful in many cases.  The only exception I am aware of is the builtin symbol `Function`, which can in fact do this, e.g. `Function[x, Print@Unevaluated[x], {HoldAll}][1+1]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Introduction

I'm not aware of any way to hold evaluation of arguments in expression of form `Inactive[f][arguments]`, which is how inactivated expressions look like. What we can do, to prevent evaluation of arguments, is to use a symbol with appropriate `Hold...` attribute, instead of `Inactive[f]` expression. This symbol should have no `DownValues` that could evaluate when arguments are passed to it.

Below I present two approaches to this problem. First is based on custom (in)activate functions, creating "dummy" symbols on the fly, for each inactivated symbol with `Hold...` attribute. Second attaches special inactivation behavior to specific symbols, which causes them to evaluate to custom inactive heads.

#### Basic examples

When we have a function with a `Hold...` attribute.

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[x_, y_] := Hold[x, y]

f[1 + 1, 2 + 2]
(* Hold[1 + 1, 4] *)
```

Ordinary inactivation of this function causes evaluation of its arguments:

```
Inactivate[f[1 + 1, 2 + 2], f]
% // FullForm
% // Activate
(* f[2, 4] *)
(* Inactive[f][2, 4] *)
(* Hold[2, 4] *)
```

so expression after inactivation and activation is different than if it would evaluate without inactivation involved.

With first, presented below, approach one can do:

```
holdingInactivate[f[1 + 1, 2 + 2], f]
% // FullForm
% // holdingActivate
(* f[1 + 1, 4] *)
(* inactive`Global`f[Plus[1, 1], 4] *)
(* Hold[1 + 1, 4] *)
```

with second approach:

```
setHoldingInactivation[f];
Inactivate[f[1 + 1, 2 + 2], f]
% // FullForm
% // Activate
(* f[1 + 1, 4] *)
(* holdingInactiveHoldFirst[Plus[1, 1], 4, Hold[Inactive[f]]] *)
(* Hold[1 + 1, 4] *)
```

---

## Implementation

Let's start with some helper symbols used in both approaches.

```
ClearAll[symPatt, holdAttrs, hasHoldAttrQ, getHoldAttr]
symPatt = Except[HoldPattern@Symbol[___], _Symbol];
holdAttrs = HoldFirst | HoldRest | HoldAll | HoldAllComplete;
hasHoldAttrQ = Function[, MemberQ[Attributes[#], holdAttrs], HoldFirst];
getHoldAttr = Function[, FirstCase[Attributes[#], holdAttrs], HoldFirst];
```

#### Dummy "inactive" symbols

In this approach we define custom `holdingInactivate`, `holdingActivate` and `ignoringHoldingInactive` functions that should be used instead of built-in `Inactivate`, `Activate` and `IgnoringInactive`.

`holdingInactivate` inactivates expression and replaces each inactive symbol, that has `Hold...` attribute, with symbol specially defined in `` inactive` `` context. This special symbol has same `Hold...` attribute as replaced one, and is formatted as inactive replaced symbol.

`holdingActivate` activates expression and replaces symbols from `` inactive` `` context with original symbols.

`ignoringHoldingInactive` returns `IgnoringInactive` expression with certain symbols replaced by `Alternatives` of original symbol and its dummy "inactive" counterpart, so returned pattern will match both active and inactive versions of expressions.

We start with some helper functions.

```
ClearAll[
    $inactiveContext, inactiveSymbolQ, toInactiveSymbol, fromInactiveSymbol,
    postprocessInactiveBoxes, defineInactiveSymbol, $inactivateExclusions,
    $inactivateExclusionsHeld, $basicInactivePatternRules,
    inactivePatternReplace
]

$inactiveContext = "inactive`";

inactiveSymbolQ[s:symPatt] := StringMatchQ[Context[s], $inactiveContext <> "*"]
inactiveSymbolQ[expr_] = False;

toInactiveSymbol[inactSym:symPatt?inactiveSymbolQ] := inactSym
toInactiveSymbol[s:symPatt] :=
    Symbol[$inactiveContext <> Context[s] <> SymbolName@Unevaluated[s]]

fromInactiveSymbol[inactSym:symPatt?inactiveSymbolQ] :=
    Symbol@StringJoin[
        StringDrop[Context[inactSym], StringLength[$inactiveContext]],
        SymbolName@Unevaluated[inactSym]
    ]
fromInactiveSymbol[s:symPatt] := s

SetAttributes[postprocessInactiveBoxes, HoldAllComplete]
postprocessInactiveBoxes[_, hISym_][
    RowBox[{TemplateBox[tbArg_, "InactiveHead", opts___], "[", args___, "]"}]
] :=
    With[{tooltip = ToString[Unevaluated[hISym], InputForm]},
        RowBox[{
            InterpretationBox[
                TemplateBox[tbArg, "InactiveHead", Tooltip -> tooltip, opts],
                hISym
            ],
            "[", args, "]"
        }]
    ]
postprocessInactiveBoxes[expr_, _][boxes_] := InterpretationBox[boxes, expr]

defineInactiveSymbol[h:symPatt /; Not@inactiveSymbolQ[h]] :=
    With[{holdAttr = getHoldAttr[h]},
        With[{hISym = toInactiveSymbol[h]},
            ClearAll[hISym];
            SetAttributes[hISym, holdAttr];
            hISym /: MakeBoxes[expr : hISym[args___], form_] :=
                postprocessInactiveBoxes[expr, hISym]@
                    MakeBoxes[Inactive[h][args], form];
            hISym
        ] /; Not@MissingQ[holdAttr]
    ]

$inactivateExclusions =
    Alternatives @@ Replace[Developer`$InactivateExclusions, {
        {sym_, "Symbol"} :> sym,
        {sym_, "Expression"} :> Blank[sym]
    }, 1];

$inactivateExclusionsHeld =
    Alternatives @@ Cases[Developer`$InactivateExclusions,
        {
            sym_ /; MemberQ[Attributes[sym], HoldAll | HoldAllComplete],
            "Symbol"
        } :> Blank[sym]
    ];

$basicInactivePatternRules = {
    excl:$inactivateExclusions :> excl,
    h:symPatt /; Not@inactiveSymbolQ[h] :>
        With[{inactSym = toInactiveSymbol[h]}, h | inactSym /; True]
};

inactivePatternReplace[expr_] :=
    Quiet[
        Unevaluated[expr] /. {
            (h : Condition | PatternTest | Repeated)[patt_, rest___] :>
                With[{replaced = inactivePatternReplace[patt]},
                    h[replaced, rest] /; True
                ],
            Verbatim[Pattern][name_, patt_] :>
                With[{replaced = inactivePatternReplace[patt]},
                    Pattern[name, replaced] /; True
                ],
            Verbatim[Verbatim][verb_] :>
                With[
                    {replaced =
                        Unevaluated[verb] /. $basicInactivePatternRules
                    },
                    Verbatim[replaced] /; True
                ],
            (bl : Blank | BlankSequence | BlankNullSequence)[
                h:symPatt /; Not@inactiveSymbolQ[h]
            ] :>
                With[{inactSym = toInactiveSymbol[h]},
                    bl[h] | bl[inactSym] /; True
                ],
            Sequence @@ $basicInactivePatternRules
        },
        RuleDelayed::rhs
    ]

SetAttributes[{
    inactiveSymbolQ, toInactiveSymbol, fromInactiveSymbol,
    defineInactiveSymbol, inactivePatternReplace
}, HoldFirst]
```

Now three "public" functions.

```
ClearAll[holdingInactivate, holdingActivate, ignoringHoldingInactive]

SetAttributes[holdingInactivate, HoldFirst]
holdingInactivate[expr_, patt_:_, opts:OptionsPattern[Inactivate]] :=
    Inactivate[Hold[expr], patt, opts] //.
        Inactive[h:Except[Except[_Symbol] | Except[patt]]][args___] :>
            With[{hISym = defineInactiveSymbol[h]},
                hISym[args] /; MatchQ[hISym, symPatt]
            ] //
        ReleaseHold

holdingActivate[expr_, patt_:_, opts:OptionsPattern[Activate]] :=
    Activate[expr, patt, opts] /. h:patt?inactiveSymbolQ :> fromInactiveSymbol[h]

ignoringHoldingInactive[expr_] :=
    IgnoringInactive[expr] /. {
        excl:$inactivateExclusionsHeld | $inactivateExclusions :> excl,
        (h:symPatt /; hasHoldAttrQ[h] && Not@inactiveSymbolQ[h])[args___] :>
            HoldPattern@h[args]
    } // Evaluate // inactivePatternReplace
```

Usage example:

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
SetAttributes[g, HoldAll]

testExpr = f[1 + 1, g[1 + 1, 1 + 1], 2, f[1 + 1]][h[2], 2, f[1 + 1]]
inactiveTestExpr = holdingInactivate[Evaluate[%], f | g | h]
% // FullForm
% // holdingActivate
```

[image: print screen of inactivation with dummy symbols]

Pattern wrapped with `ignoringHoldingInactive` will match both active and inactive versions of same expression:

```
MatchQ[testExpr, ignoringHoldingInactive[testExpr]]
(* True *)
MatchQ[inactiveTestExpr, ignoringHoldingInactive[testExpr]]
(* True *)
```

It can be also used to manipulate inactive expression:

```
inactiveTestExpr /. {
    ignoringHoldingInactive[f[arg : 1 + _]] :> Hold[arg],
    ignoringHoldingInactive[gExpr_g] :> 5 + gExpr
}
```

[image: print screen of replacement using ignoringHoldingInactive]

#### Attaching special inactivation behavior to symbols

In this approach we attach special behavior to some of symbols that are supposed to be inactivated. Inactivation and activation is performed using built-in `Inactivate` and `Activate`.

We set special `UpValues`, for e.g. `f` symbol, causing `Inactive[f][args]` to evaluate to `holdingInactive...[args, Hold@Inactive[f]]`, where `holdingInactive...` is head with same `Hold...` attribute as `f`. We keep `f` itself in last argument of `holdingInactive...`, this way expression can be appropriately formatted and, when activated, can automatically evaluate to original `f[args]`.

Since special behavior, during both inactivation and activation, depends on evaluation, `Inactive[f][args]` expressions will not be replaced by `holdingInactive...` expression if it's inside some holding wrapper itself. This will not cause any problems with evaluation of `f`'s arguments (since it's in holding wrapper they will not evaluate), but under the hood inactive expression can be slightly inconsistent and can contain both `Inactive[f][args]` and `holdingInactive...[args, Hold@Inactive[f]]`, which might be inconvenient when manipulating inactive expression. When part of inactive expression is allowed to evaluate, then held, then activated, it may happen that we end up with expression containing `holdingInactive...` that will remain there until it's allowed to evaluate.

```
ClearAll[holdingInactive, setHoldingInactivation]

(* Define four holdingInactive... functions one for each Hold... atribute. *)
Scan[
    With[{head = Symbol["holdingInactive"<>ToString[#]]},
        ClearAll[head];
        SetAttributes[head, #];
        head[args___, Hold[h:Except@Inactive[_]]] := h[args];
        head /: MakeBoxes[expr:head[args___, Hold[h:Inactive[_]]], form_] :=
            InterpretationBox[#, expr]&@MakeBoxes[h[args], form];
        holdingInactive[#] = head
    ]&,
    holdAttrs
]

SetAttributes[setHoldingInactivation, Listable]
setHoldingInactivation[h_Symbol] :=
    With[{holdAttr = getHoldAttr[h]},
        With[{holdingInactiveFunc = holdingInactive[holdAttr]},
            h /: Inactive[h] =
                Function[,
                    holdingInactiveFunc[##, Hold@Inactive[h]],
                    HoldAllComplete
                ];
            h
        ] /; Not@MissingQ[holdAttr]
    ]
```

Usage example:

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
SetAttributes[g, HoldAll]

setHoldingInactivation[{f, g}]
(* {f, g} *)

f[1 + 1, g[1 + 1, 1 + 1], 2, f[1 + 1]][h[2], 2, f[1 + 1]]
Inactivate[Evaluate[%], f | g | h]
% // FullForm
% // Activate
```

[image: print screen of result with custom inactive heads]

Comment: This is very nice and far reaching with plenty of background info, +1

Answer (score 3):

I think you are not properly aware of how the kernel is evaluating your expression and how the front-end is printing the result.

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[x_] := (x = 42)
```

Now if `f` were to see `1 + 1` as an argument in either evaluated or unevaluated form, it would complain.

```
f[1 + 1]
```

[image: msg]

```
f[2]
```

[image: msg]

but it doesn't complain when `Inactive[f][1 + 1]` is evaluated because `f` is treated as an inert symbol, never gets evaluated and never sees ***any*** argument at all.

```
Inactive[f][1 + 1] // FullForm
```

> `Inactive[f][2]`

Just because the front-end pretty prints `Inactive[f][2]` as `f[2]` in an output cell doesn't mean that somehow `f` has lost it `HoldFirst`  attribute.

#### Update

This is in response to the OP's comment.

Let's trace `Inactive[f][Print[Hello]]`.

```
Trace[Inactive[f][Print[Hello]]]
```

[image: trace]

You see that `Print[Hello]` is first thing evaluated and returns `Null`. Then it looks as if `f` is applied to `Null`, but that's not the case, since if it were, the `f[2]` in the trace would be followed by its result, but there is no result.

The `f[2]` is produced because the front-end pretty prints `HoldForm[Inactive[f][Null]]` as `f[2]`, which is the final returned value; `f` has not been evaluated at all, not with any argument, not even null, during the trace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but I don't understand it.  I read your answer like 5 times and I still don't understand it.  I'm just a dumb guy.  Consider `f[Print["Hello"]]` vs `Inactive[f][Print["Hello"]]`.  The first version doesn't print `"Hello"` because of `f`'s `HoldFirst` attribute.  But `Inactive[f][Print["Hello"]]` *does* print it because that attribute is suppressed by `Inactive`.  How do I prevent this effect?

Comment: @QuantumDot. No, in the case of `Inactive[f][Print["Hello"]]`, the `f` is not evaluated at all, not with any argument, If it were evaluated the argument it would receive would be `Null`, which is what `Print["Hello"]` evaluates to. What you see printed is a side effect not the value of `Print["Hello"]`.

Comment: @QuantumDot. I have edited the answer. I hope it will be a little clearer now.

Comment: I really feel, you're insistent on sidestepping the actual question. *If* `f` was evaluated, it *would* receive `Print["Hello"]` as its argument, because symbols with attribute `HoldFirst` are passed their argument unevaluated. It seems pretty clear, that `Inactive[f][1+1] // Activate` is not equivalent to `f[1+1]` and I can see how this behavior may be undesirable.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. Sure I'm sidestepping. I have to. With the form `Inactive[f][...]`, which is basis for the OP question, there is no way `f` can receive anything as its argument. I'm trying to make the OP see that.

Comment: Ok, I thought the implicit XY problem was acknowledged by everyone, but perhaps not.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The same is also true for constructins like `Hold[f][1+1]//ReleaseHold` or any other technique that is aimed at altering the order of evaluation. So I agree with m_goldberg that this behavior is consistent with the general workings of Mathematica.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Also, what is the XY problem?

Comment: @sebhofer I agree that this is to be expected, though it may be very different from what *the user* expected/desired. XY problem is when OP wants to solve X, but thinks that problem Y is a minimal example / best way to solve X / if only he could figure out Y, he'd manage X, etc. The Y problem (what OP asked) is, in this case, interesting in itself, but maybe he should take a step back, look at the big picture and try to solve X differently.